# Is it possible to pass the fields of an array to a function with variant parameter array?

Tags: excel, vba

I am in the following situation: I have a function, that takes a ParamArray of type variant and generates a string from the keywords given in its ParamArray in a special manner by execution mergeToString.

```
Function function1(ParamArray var() As Variant) As String
    For i = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
       function1 = mergeToString(function1, CStr(var(i))
    Next i
End Function
```

In another subroutine, I have an array of strings obtained from the Split Function in VBA and want to use it as an input for function1

```
Sub displayFCTN1()
    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split("foo|bar", "|")
    'and here I ran out of ideas...
    Debug.Print function1(**???**)
End Sub
```

The two lines

```
function1(**???**)
function1("foo","bar")
```

should be equivalent the first somehow using arr().

In Matlab this is relatively easy - I know, VBA is not Matlab, still this might help as an extended description of my problem:
you could most likely do it by using the colon operator in **Matlab**

```
function1(arr(:))
```

since then the fields of the array arr() count as "free" parameters.

Is there something comparable to this in VBA? I tried ReDim already, that somehow didn't do the job (as far as I tried).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just a tad bit confused on what exactly you are asking. But just an observation: is `mergeToString()` essentially the same thing as the built-in `Join()` function? You've also declared `varStr` in function1, but it's unused.

Comment: When you pass an array to the paramarray, you get this: var(0)(0) "foo" : function1 = mergeToString(function1, CStr(var(0)(i)) probably will work when you call function1(arr).

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Sorry for the unused varStr. I corrected it. Concerning the mergeToString() function: In the simplest form as used above, simply concatenates the input strings. It actually offers some more variety when adding more arguments (sorting, layouting,...). If that is, what `Join()` does, then yes. Sorry, I am a total beginner at VBA..

Comment: @EvR I wouldn't like to change function1 because I would lose compatibility with calls like `function1("foo","bar")`  in this case, which are already in use within the wrapping code. Also, I would prefer a solution like described in Matlab code over an if statement (to query if the variant array is only of length 1 and then convert it to a variant array...) since this is also a bit unflexible.. (I couldn't do function calls like `function1(arr(),"abc")`.

Comment: I don't think VBA can pass array-items directly to ParamArray-items .You could use a helper procedure but that will be maximized to 30 arguments.  I'll post this procedure as an answer

Comment: Could you change `function1` so it works with both types?  If the `ubound` of `var` is the same as the `lbound` then you can be pretty sure you've passed a single array, otherwise deal with it as per your original code.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yeah, I thought about this too, but as described earlier, I would lose compatibility with function calls like `function1(arr(),"abc")`, wouldn't I? And what about `function1("abc", arr())`?

Comment: I missed the `function1(arr(),"abc")` as it's hidden at the end of one of your comments  and not in the question.  I was just working on the assumption it would either be two strings, or a number of arrays containing two strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test, whether the first item of array is array:

```
Sub FFF()
    MsgBox Func1("foo", "bar")
    MsgBox Func1(Split("foo|bar", "|"))
End Sub

Function Func1$(ParamArray var() As Variant)
    Dim s$, x%, args
    args = IIf(IsArray(var(0)), var(0), var)
    '//Do something
    For x = 0 To UBound(args)
        s = s & args(x) & "|"
    Next
    Func1 = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: This will immediately cause problems as soon as you want to do something like `function1("abc", arr())` since it is designed to check the first element of the parameter array only, right? Sorry, if the need for this kind of flexibility was not clear so far...

Answer (score 0):

A workaround as mentioned in the comments above

```
Sub displayFCTN1()
        Dim arr() As String
        arr() = Split("foo|bar", "|")
        Myhelper arr
    End Sub

    Sub Myhelper(arr)
    Select Case UBound(arr)
    Case 0: Debug.Print function1(arr(0))
    Case 1: Debug.Print function1(arr(0), arr(1))
    Case 2: Debug.Print function1(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))
    Case 3: Debug.Print function1(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2), arr(3))
    Case 4: Debug.Print function1(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2), arr(3), arr(4))
    'etc up to 29.
    Case Else
    End Select
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This does require a change to `function1` code, but should still work with orginal.

```
Sub Test()

    Debug.Print function1("foo", "bar")

    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split("foo|bar", "|")
    Debug.Print function1(arr)

End Sub

Function function1(ParamArray var() As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long

    If UBound(var) = 0 Then
        For i = LBound(var(0)) To UBound(var(0))
            'function1 = Join(var(0), "|")
            function1 = mergeToString(function1, CStr(var(0)(i)))
        Next i
    Else
        'Original code.
        For i = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
           'function1 = Join(var, "|")
           function1 = mergeToString(function1, CStr(var(i)))
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```